# what is the corresponding field name of event_dim according to new BigQuery export schema?

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

[Link to schema](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512)

I am trying to find event_dim records according to new schema.Could not find it.

Answer (score 1):

The last line of the migration script on the same webpage says "`UNNEST(event_dim) AS event`". And `UNNEST` is described in the [BigQuery  documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest) as:

> The `UNNEST` operator takes an `ARRAY` and returns a table, with one row for each element in the `ARRAY`.

In other words: every row represents an event now, in stead of one row containig a `RECORD` with multiple events.

Also the fields of `event_dim` are mapped to slightly different names, as you can see in the first `SELECT` at the beginning of the script:

- `event_dim.timestamp_micros` is mapped to `event_timestamp`
- `event_dim.previous_timestamp_micros` is mapped to `event_previous_timestamp`
- `event_dim.name` is mapped to `event_name`
- etc...

In conclusion: the main difference is that one row contains exactly one event in the new schema. Next to that, the fields are renamed.

Comment: But where did you find event_dim in new schema? there is no field name corresponding to event_dim in  new schema.

Comment: Improved the answer by explaining the the fields are also renamed. I hope this helps you find the data you need

Comment: Thanks ! I understand what you are saying. but I am still stuck with this problem. could you please look into that?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52454515/how-to-write-bigquery-event-dim-record-according-to-new-schema